# Can API-Gateway check the input parameters and reject (without passing it to Lambda) an HTTP request?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I would like to use API-Gateway (plus Lambda) to realize a PetStore Restful API. One of the API entry point is and the body of the POST request needs to contain 'name'. See the [PetStore definition](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v2.0/yaml/petstore-expanded.yaml) snippet below:

```
/pets/
   POST

definitions:
  NewPet:
    required:
      - name  
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      tag:
        type: string
```

Can I make API-Gateway smart enough to reject requests that does not contain the required field (in this case, 'name'), without calling the Lambda (yes, I understand I am able to check the input fields inside the Lambda function, but I wonder if I can avoid it)? -- this would save a lot of time and complexity to deal with the corner case.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved through using request validation set in the "method request" settings.

[image: method request settings]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the request body rather than query string you need to create a model;

APIs > {ApiName} > Models

In the sidebar.

Create your model using [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step.html)

In the API Gateway, choose to validate the request body then select your created model in the dropdown.

[API Gateway config page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NZgF.png)